# Numeric values appear different in a .csv file

Tags: r, csv, import

I have a dataset containing numeric values that looks like this:

```
> head(df$back_price, 20)
[1] "12"      "12"      "12"      "12"      "12"      "12.5"    "12"      "12"       "11"      "11"      [11] "11"      "11"      "10.5"    "10.5"    "10.5"    "10.5"    "10.5"    "10.5"    "9.8"     "9.46667"
```

I want to use this values in a .csv file and therefore I wrote them to .csv file. However when I open my .csv file and seperate the values using text to columns I get an output like this: https://www.flickr.com/photos/113328996@N07/26509182333/in/dateposted-public/

Any thoughts on how I can make sure the values are stored in a normal way in a .csv file?

Comment: You are showing the output of `back_price` column and rounded the `back_size` in the image.  In the image, I guess it is a formatting issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you show, I guess that the problem comes from the wrong decimal separator. Try to specify it as a coma, in your case:

```
write.table(df, file="output.csv", sep=";", dec=",")
```

Comment: I rather think, they need to set `quote = FALSE`. There is no indication that they have a system that uses `,` as a decimal separator.

Comment: @Roland that's because I'm French ;-)